# how to merge many time series with different length in R

Tags: r, time-series

I'm retrieving some data from a server and get around 200 time series objects all of them with different length. This is not operative so would like to merge them into one object and write NA in those positions where there is no data available. Also for each series I have more than one variable. I tried with a loop but still is not operative, there must be a more elegant way of sorting this out. For instance assume I have the following:

```
    library(zoo)
    a=zoo(matrix(rnorm(300), 100, 3),Sys.Date()-100:1)
    b=zoo(matrix(rnorm(375), 125, 3),Sys.Date()-125:1)
    c=zoo(matrix(rnorm(525), 175, 3),Sys.Date()-175:1)
    d=zoo(matrix(rnorm(450), 150, 3),Sys.Date()-150:1)
    e=list(a,b,c,d)
    z=do.call(merge,e)
```

EDIT: this works

Comment: @Joshua Ulrich thanks for your reply. Yes that works for this example but please note that I'm retrieving more than 200 series. If there is no other way I'll do this but maybe there is an alternative creating a list or something similar.

Comment: If `file.names` is a character vector holding the file names then `z <- read.zoo(file.names, ...other arguments...)` will read them all in and merge them to produce `z`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `do.call` together with `merge`. It iteratively merges a list of zoo time series.

```
do.call(merge,list(a,b,c,d))
```

I think the missing values should be filled with NAs.

Comment: thanks! I just have edited the code. I tried but don't know how to extract one specific variable from one particular series say second variable of b series.

Comment: Please check whether you have duplicate colnames in your list of zoo objects. If so, `do.call(merge,...)` will produce some weird colnames. You can either assign unique colnames before the merge or take care of the colnames after the merge operation.

Comment: That's what I mean:`library(zoo);
a=zoo(data.frame(a=rnorm(10,0,0.1)),1:10);
b=zoo(data.frame(b=rnorm(10,0,0.1)),1:10);
do.call(merge,list(a,b));
do.call(merge,list(a,a));` The last line produces weird colnames since the original ones are not unique (i,e. both are `a`).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add the zoo objects as new columns, the `cbind` function is your friend.

```
data <- cbind(a,b,c,d)
```

The beauty of zoo objects is that they can be ragged. Hence, NA values are automatically returned when the length of timeseries differ. Plus, zoo has a nice multivariate timeseries autoplot function, among many other things:

```
plot(data)
```